# can a Windows 8 tablet run a Microsoft Access form?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-access

can a Windows 8 tablet run a  Microsoft Access form?
thanks in advance, Nahaniel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows 8 tablets can run all traditional desktop applications, including Access.

Windows **RT** tablets cannot run desktop applications.

Comment: Of course MS hasn't confirmed or denied whether Access will ever be ported to ARM in the future (to go with the rest of Office RT), so it *is* a possibility, however remote.